# reading multiple csv files and putting it in different sheets in excel not working

Tags: java, file-io, apache-poi

I am trying to read few csv files which are present inside a folder and putting the absolute paths inside a list and then looping to the list and inserting data into excel in different sheets but for some reason only last loop is overwriting everything.

```
package excel;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class FileReading {

    public static void csvToXLS(String filename, String sheetno) {
        try {
            String csvFile = filename; //csv file address
            String excelFile = "E:\\test.xls"; //xlsx file address
            HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet(sheetno);
            String currentLine = null;
            int RowNum = 0;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String str[] = currentLine.split(",");
                HSSFRow currentRow = sheet.createRow(RowNum);
                RowNum++;
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                    currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
            workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "Exception in try");
        }
    }

    public static List listOfFiles() {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] files = new File("f:\\csv").listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                results.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = listOfFiles();
        int size = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            csvToXLS(list.get(i).toString(), "sheet" + i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're re-creating and saving the `Workbook` every time you call `csvToXLS`, so only the last call survives, overwriting all others.

Create the `Workbook` only once, before you start your `for` loop, passing it into `csvToXLS`.  then that method will create a new `Sheet` on an existing `Workbook`.  Then after the `for` loop ends, you can write out and save the `Workbook`.

Comment: I would bring the code that creates the output stream and calls `write` outside the `csvToXLS` method, so that you only write it once.

Comment: you want to return the workbook and write it outside

Answer (score 1):

I did this thanks for the idea @rgettman

```
package excel;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class CsvToXlx {

    public static void csvToXLSX(HSSFWorkbook workBook,String filename, String sheetno) {
        try {
            String csvFile = filename; //csv file address
            String excelFile = "E:\\test.xls"; //xlsx file address
            //HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet(sheetno);
            String currentLine = null;
            int RowNum = 0;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String str[] = currentLine.split(",");
                HSSFRow currentRow = sheet.createRow(RowNum);
                RowNum++;
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                    currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
            workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "Exception in try");
        }
    }

    public static List listOfFiles() {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] files = new File("f:\\csv").listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                results.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = listOfFiles();
        int size = list.size();
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            csvToXLSX(workBook,list.get(i).toString(), "sheet" + i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```